# How to clone a div when it's dropped and not when drag start

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-droppable

By using jQuery UI I would like to  I create a clone of a certain div only when dropped. This div should be cloned in the same point when you start to drag and ready to be dragged again.

For example in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p0ozboau/1/) is possible to clone the green elements, in the initial position, only when they are dropped?

This is my JS:

```
$(function() {
  $("#dragrabble-one").draggable({
    helper: 'clone'
  });
  $("#dragrabble-two").draggable({
    helper: 'clone'
  });
  $("#dragrabble-three").draggable({
    helper: 'clone'
  });
  $("#dragrabble-four").draggable({
    helper: 'clone'
  });
  $("#dragrabble-five").draggable({
    helper: 'clone'
  });
  $("#dragrabble-six").draggable({
    helper: 'clone'
  });
  $("#dragrabble-seven").draggable({
    helper: 'clone'
  });
  $("#dragrabble-eight").draggable({
    helper: 'clone'
  });
  $("#dragrabble-one").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $("#dragrabble-two").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $("#dragrabble-three").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $("#dragrabble-four").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $("#dragrabble-five").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $("#dragrabble-six").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $("#dragrabble-seven").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $("#dragrabble-eight").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $("#droppable-box").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var clone = ui.helper.clone();
      clone.draggable();
      clone.appendTo('#droppable-box');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to reinitialize the draggable element after cloning, I have changed the JS Function `drop` refer the below code.

```
$("#droppable-box").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var clone = ui.helper.clone();
      clone.appendTo('#droppable-box');
      clone.draggable({
        helper: "clone"
      });
    }
  });
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("#dragrabble-one").draggable({
    helper: 'clone'
  });
  $("#dragrabble-two").draggable({
    helper: 'clone'
  });
  $("#dragrabble-three").draggable({
    helper: 'clone'
  });
  $("#dragrabble-four").draggable({
    helper: 'clone'
  });
  $("#dragrabble-five").draggable({
    helper: 'clone'
  });
  $("#dragrabble-six").draggable({
    helper: 'clone'
  });
  $("#dragrabble-seven").draggable({
    helper: 'clone'
  });
  $("#dragrabble-eight").draggable({
    helper: 'clone'
  });
  $("#dragrabble-one").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $("#dragrabble-two").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $("#dragrabble-three").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $("#dragrabble-four").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $("#dragrabble-five").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $("#dragrabble-six").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $("#dragrabble-seven").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $("#dragrabble-eight").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $("#droppable-box").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var clone = ui.helper.clone();
      clone.appendTo('#droppable-box');
      clone.draggable({
        helper: "clone"
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  height: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: green;
}

#droppable-box {
  height: 400px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: lightgray;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<span>Drag green boxes onto gray dropzone</span>

<div class="container">
  <div class="box" id="dragrabble-one"></div>
  <br />
  <div class="box" id="dragrabble-two"></div>
  <br />
  <div class="box" id="dragrabble-three"></div>
  <br />
  <div class="box" id="dragrabble-four"></div>
  <br />
  <div class="box" id="dragrabble-five"></div>
  <br />
  <div class="box" id="dragrabble-six"></div>
  <br />
  <div class="box" id="dragrabble-seven"></div>
  <br />
  <div class="box" id="dragrabble-eight"></div>
  <br />
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div id="droppable-box">Drop Zone</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that with this JS the element is cloned on the droppable area and not in the same position from where is dragged at the beginning (left)

Comment: @GoePorsh The question is ambiguous, how are you saying that is cloning from the dropping area? can you please describe the problem properly, by adding text inside the draggable elements and highlight the issue for readers sake?